# Xamarin designer Exception in visual studio 2015 for android

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

**Hello**!
I change and save the files *.axml, but designer crashed with error.
I reinstalled Visual Studio, SDK Ansroid, Xamarin, Windows 10, but does not work. My System absolutely clean.

**My system:**
Windows 10,
Visual Studio 2015 professional (Update3),
Xamarin version 4.2.0.680,
Android SDK Tools version 25.2.2,
SDK Platform Android 6.0, 5.0.1, 4.42,
JDK 1.8

Help me, please.

**Exception:**

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:21.6275] Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:21.8140] Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage Warning: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:22.0035] Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:26.0092] Updated license: Android VSProfessional
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:26.2787] Updated license: iOS VSProfessional
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:40.9255] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:41.3044] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:41.5261] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:41.7399] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane Error: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:48.3852] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:49.4008] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:49.7591] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:50.1029] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:50.4310] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane Error: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:54.5138] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:55.3556] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:55.6798] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:56.1944] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:25:56.5547] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane Error: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:35:28.4616] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Document.Close(vsSaveChanges Save)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 623
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.<OpenViewCodeAsync>b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:35:29.2194] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:35:29.5710] 
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:35:30.3170] INFO: Changing layoutlib, from 0 to 23
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-16 09:35:30.6881]
```

Comment: Report the issue to Xamarin, and hope they can fix it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be an issue of the latest Xamarin Android Designer needing the JDK 8 64 bit. Please see the release notes here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/

Relevant text:

> Note: Xamarin.Android 7.0 requires [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to use the Android Nougat (API 24) APIs. You can continue to use earlier versions of the JDK if targeting earlier Android API levels:
>
> [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) - up to API 24+
>
> [JDK 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) - up to API 23
>
> [JDK 1.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) - up to API 20
>
> Additionally, a 64-bit version of the JDK is required to use [custom controls in the Android designer.](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#androiddesignercustomcontrols)
>
> The simplest option is to install the 64-bit version of JDK 1.8 since it is backwards compatible with all of the previous API levels and supports the new Android designer features.
>
> (One unfortunate complication with JDK 1.8 is that is not compatible with the outdated version of Proguard that is included in the Android SDK. Currently this will cause an error "Unsupported class version number [52.0]" when attempting to use the Proguard or Multidex features in Xamarin.Android. See [44187](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44187).)